# React BMI Calculator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am stuck on building an imperial BMI calculator in React.js. Does anyone help me to convert the matric calculator to imperial?

```
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState()
  const [mass, setMass] = useState()
  const [resultNumber, setResultNumber] = useState(0)
  const [resultText, setResultText] = useState('')

  const handleCalculate = () => {
    let imc = (mass * 703) / height ** 2
    setResultNumber(imc.toFixed(2))

    if (imc < 18.5) {
      setResultText( "Underweight" );
    } else if (imc > 18.5 && imc < 25) {
      setResultText( "Normal Weight" );
    } else if (imc >= 25 && imc < 30) {
      setResultText( "Overweight" );
    } else {
      setResultText( "Obesity");
    }
  }
```

This code is a matric calculator I need to build an imperial calculator like FEET and INCHES and POUNDS how can I create it.

Comment: It already is Imperial formula. 703 is a magic number to convert pounds to KG and inches to meters. In metric you dont need 703 because the values already are KG and meter. 

But if you also want to support FEET then you need to add in some conversion from FEET to inches.

Comment: Can I get the formula?

Comment: Imperial formula : (lbs X 703)/(inches * inches), 1 foot = 12 inches.
Metric formula: kg / (meter * meter)